# React.JS Inject a HTML file into another HTML file.

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm currently learning React.js, knowing that it is just the view of MVC. I have come from a Angular stack and I'm starting to worry about a few things with React.js.

One of them being if you have a partial html file how can you inject that file into another to build a functioning html file.

For example. How would i go about including a header, body and footer files into one?

I've read about dangourouslyinnerHTML which I don't want to use for XSS reasons. Is there a different way that I'm missing? Or is this something I will have to get gulp to compile?

Comment: You use components with react, so each component is a set of HTML that you can "inject" into another.

Comment: As @Ivan says, you would have a Header component, a Body component, and a Footer component, and your (e.g.) App component would render all three components.

Comment: And those components have to be built in a js file? instead of a html?

Comment: @MaxLynn Yes. The HTML goes in the render function of each React class (which go in js files).

Comment: alright so you have a js file that has your html inside that then gets compiled to html in your html file. Pretty interesting way to go about it. Thanks for your help. Mind if i ask another question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the React paradigm is a bit different. React is built on the concept of components which contain events, HTML, and CSS in JavaScript.

For example, you could have a `Head`, `Body` and `Footer` component that would all be rendered in your `App` component. This example uses JSX:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Head />
        <Body />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The `Head`, `Body` and `Footer` components would look similar, each with their own render function that returns HTML in it.

I recommend reading the [Thinking in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) section of the React Docs.

Comment: Ah I've read about this... Ok and those components would then have your html inside a js file. This makes more sense now. So if I could I'd like to ask the question how would you do this without JSX? As I've read its been deprecated?

Comment: JSX has absolute __not__ been deprecated

Comment: JSX is THE way to write React code. A transpiler will take JSX and turn it into normal JS for you.

Comment: I see. My bad not sure where I got that from then. Thats great team. Thanks for your help. I'm on my way to being a pro haha